# Why are there two identical accounts showing notes in Notes app?

Tags: macos, mac, icloud

I just got a Macbook Pro and I set it up with my iCloud account, and I noticed that when I go into the Notes app, the left pane [that displays the accounts it's grabbing the notes from] is showing two identical accounts.

If I secondary-click one of them, I see a context menu with a disabled 'Delete' option.

How can I force Notes to only display one account (and preferably also completely remove one of them too)? Or is there a good reason why there would be identicals?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this webpage, this problem is now resolved: http://elsutech.com/fix-duplicated-icloud-accounts-os-x-yosemite.html

1. Click the Apple icon on the desktop and then click System Preferences.
2. In System Preferences, click Internet Accounts.
3. Select your iCloud account in the Accounts pane on the left, then click the '-' button at the bottom-left of the window.
4. Confirm the pending actions, and then restart your computer.
5. After restarting the computer, repeat steps 1 to 3.
6. Click the button 'enter password' at the top of the right pane, and enter your password.
7. Then reselect what you want to be synchronised.

Open Notes and you should now only see notes being displayed from a single account.